# Binary search attempt

Tags: python, binary-search

I've heard about the binary search in an intro class I took a couple months ago, remembered how it worked and read [this article](https://reprog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/are-you-one-of-the-10-percent/), so I attempted to write my first binary search in Python. It works, but when I look at other people's attempts in the article, their code looks cleaner and a bit different.

My two main questions are:

1. What can I do to optimize my code from here?
2. Am I even performing a true binary search?

```
def binsearch(mylist, keyval):
large = len(mylist)-1
small = 0
temp = (len(mylist)-1)/2
key = 'undefined'
flag = 0
while flag == 0:
    if mylist[small] == keyval:
        key = small
        flag = 1
    elif mylist[large] == keyval:
        key = large
        flag = 1
    elif mylist[temp] == keyval:
        key = temp
        flag = 1
    elif temp + 1 == large or temp -1 == small:
        flag = 1
    if keyval > mylist[temp]:
        small = temp
        temp = small + (large - small)/2
    elif keyval < mylist[temp]:
        large = temp
        temp = temp - (large-small)/2
return key
```

Comment: Please don't invalidate answers by editing your code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this code has a few bugs.

`binsearch([], 1)` throws an `IndexError`.

`binsearch([2], 1)` goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: if len(mylist) == 0:
  return 'undefined'
 elif len(mylist) == 1 and keyval == mylist[0]:
  return 0
 elif len(mylist) == 1 and keyval != mylist[0]:
  return 'undefined'

Comment: added those lines of code right to the top to handle those errors thanks for the input mjolka

Comment: still curious on how to optimize my code, since binary searches are supposed to run very quickly

Comment: @user85519 I found another test case that fails: [0, 0, 1, 2], key = 1. I'd suggest having a look at the implementation [here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/11model/BinarySearch.java.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have complicated the neatness of the binary search somewhat, but it is an honest attempt. However here are some comments to your code:

- *Too many variables* – There is no need for the `flag` and the `key` variable, they are only adding to the confusion. Instead it would be better to use a `mid` variable, and use this a little more
- *Avoid `flag` variables* – In most cases instead of using a flag variable like you have done, you could have a `while True:` loop, and then use `break` to get out of it. In this particular case it is even better to use a `while small <= large:` loop...
- In addition most of the comment by [Curt F](//codereview.stackexchange.com/users/76662/curt-f) in [his answer](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/106083/78136) applies to your code as well :-)

Taking all of these into account, here is a new variant, rather heavily modified from your original code:

```
def binary_search(my_list, key):
    assert my_list == sorted(my_list)

    large = len(my_list) -1
    small = 0

    while (small <= large):
        mid = (small + large) // 2 )
        # print small, mid, large, " - ", my_list[mid], "~", key
        if my_list[mid] < key:
            small = mid + 1
        elif my_list[mid] > key:
            large = mid - 1
        else:
            return mid

    raise ValueError
```

This code is tested rather heavily, and should work nicely. It's rather similar to code from [Wikipedia's binary search algorithm](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).